# how to use text box in PHP to show database data?

Tags: php

I'm trying to this syntax, but it's not working....

```
echo' < input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Enter States" value=" < ?php echo $_POST['state']; ?>"> ';
```

It's show error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'state' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'.
```

How can I resolve this `error`. Please help me for the same.

Thanks in Advance Guys!

Comment: Please use the code block (Button {}) to show code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong: `echo'hello';`

this is right: `echo('hello');` // best way imho

this is right: `echo 'right';`

Your code could look like this:

```
echo ('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Enter States" value="' . $_POST['state'] . '">');
```

The code above works, but if the user enters special characters it can break the HTML of your site (and mean a security issue). So you should use this:

```
echo ('<input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Enter States" value="' . htmlentities($_POST['state']) . '">');
```

Comment: The first one is also syntactically valid, just not pretty.

Comment: @mario - surprising... but you are right.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this code:

```
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='state' name='state' placeholder='Enter States' value='<?php echo $_POST["state"]; ?>'>";
```